# Chrome DevTools "search" doesn't work (i.e. when searching for "<h1>", which obviously exsists, results in 0 found). Also preview mode isn't accurate

Tags: google-chrome, devtools

My Chrome DevTools are MESSED UP.  As stated in my question, all search results in 0.  Also, the preview mode is NOT accurate. For instance, when testing at 1282px for a site I'm working on, it shows that top navigation is totally fine (all on one line) - but that is because there is an X axis overflow, which I can scroll left and right - as there's a white bar to the right of the overflow. However, when testing at 1282px on LIVE outside of dev tools, there is no overflow and the top nav is scrunched/squished.

I tried completely uninstalling Chrome from my control panel, and re-installing it. I tried clearing cache. Neither of these worked.

Has anyone seen this before?

One final thing, DevTools search does seem to work in Incognito mode (but preview is still messed up)

Can I get help?

I tried un-installing Chrome and re-installing. Clearing cache.